# Install a PHP extension from .tgz file

Tags: linux, centos, php-extension

I download the latest http-extension for php to install on the CentOS, the file is a tgz file, can anyone help me by installing this extension.

Thank,

Answer (score 4):

Linux system usually has a pear repository on it. [To install](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php) `pear` (assuming that you have `wget` installed. If not, install it with `yum install wget`):

```
wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
php go-pear.phar
```

After installing/configuring pear on your system, you can install php extensions like this:

```
pear install foo-bar.tgz
```